# C# function to convert screen-space coordinates to worldspace coordinates, at specific Z position?

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a 2D game, rendered as 3D.

When clicking on my game, I want it to convert those screen space pixel coordinates into worldspace coordinates, knowing the Z axis point (0) that the point should hit.

How can I do this with a function?

I am using XNA with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting from 2d to 3d is unprojecting. there is a built in method within xna for this:

```
 Vector3 3dWorldPosition = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(2DscreenVector & desired Z comp, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
```

Comment: That didn't work. When zooming in, and scaling increases, it gets offset.